# How to detect changed of a input from javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect whenever the content of the input field has changed. For example is the event of the button, how can i detect this change?

```js
$('#kunden_plz').on('propertychange change keyup paste input',function(){
 console.log("PLZ: "+$(this).val());
});

$('#change_plz').on('click',function(){
  $('#kunden_plz').val("12345");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Plz: </label> 
 <input id="kunden_plz" class="plz" size="5" name="plz" value="" type="text"  /> 
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="change_plz" type="button">Change</button>
```

I hope someone has a idea, excepted this:

```
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
<input type='hidden'id='txtVar' value=''/>

$("#btn").click(function(){
   $("#txtVar").val("1234").change();
});

$(document).on('change', '#txtVar', function () {
   alert("called");
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How i can detect a change of a input field from a javascript event?

Comment: So if x = "aa"  and you change it to "abbbb" you want to check if value was changed when event is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event will not be triggered when you change them programmatically. However [`.trigger(event)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)/[`.triggerHandler(event)`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) can be used to trigger the event.

```js
$('#kunden_plz').on('propertychange change keyup paste input',function(){
 console.log("PLZ: "+$(this).val());
});

$('#change_plz').on('click',function(){
  $('#kunden_plz').val("12345").trigger('change');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Plz: </label> 
 <input id="kunden_plz" class="plz" size="5" name="plz" value="" type="text"  /> 
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="change_plz" type="button">Change</button>
```

Second option is Polling **Not Recommended**

```js
var previousVal;
var pollInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var val = $('#kunden_plz').val();
    if (val !== previousVal) {
      // It changed
      console.log("PLZ: "+val);
    }
    previousVal = val;
}, 100);

$('#change_plz').on('click',function(){
  $('#kunden_plz').val("12345").trigger('change');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Plz: </label> 
 <input id="kunden_plz" class="plz" size="5" name="plz" value="" type="text"  /> 
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="change_plz" type="button">Change</button>
```

Comment: The change of the input field comes from another javascript file which i cant change with this trigger function!

Comment: @Provie9, Use `clearInterval` once change is detected